# Flutter Complex Parsing Json Undefined getter "List<Type>'

Tags: flutter, jsonparser

I am trying to parse a complex json file into my application I am getting an error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'List'. I can't get the name of the route at my List of routes, but can get everything else.
I don't understand where this is happening and how to fix it.

My code:

```
void openBottomSheet() {
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return FutureBuilder<DriverDataModel>(
        future: mongoApi.getMongoData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final driver = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: driver.data.routes.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${driver.data.routes.name}'),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.directions),
                    onTap: () {
                      drawPolyLine.cleanPolyline();
                      getCurrentLocation();
                      routesCoordinates.isInCourse(driver.data.routes);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),                
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      );
    });
```

Json reponse:

```
{

"success": true,
"data": {
    "_id": "600773ac1bde5d10e89511d1",
    "name": "Joselito",
    "truck": "5f640232ab8f032d18ce0137",
    "phone": "*************",
    "routes": [
        {
            "name": "Tere city",
            "week": [
                {
                    "short_name": "mon"
                }
            ],
            "coordinates": [
                {
                    "lat": -22.446938,
                    "lng": -42.982084
                },
                {
                    "lat": -22.434384,
                    "lng": -42.978511
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-01-20T00:05:00.717Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-20T00:05:00.717Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I used https://app.quicktype.io/ to create my model and successfully parsed. How ever, when I tried to print the name of my route inside of my routes's list a get that getter error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fartem almost answered right except you need to dynamically access your items by index (not just the first item). In your code on the line where you use the function `itemBuilder` in `ListView.builder`, instead of

`itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {`

I would suggest using

`itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {`

since the second parameter is an INDEX. Thus, to be able to get the name for each of the items in the list you would have to use that index:

`title: Text('${driver.data.routes[i].name}'),`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Routes is an array, you can try to calling it by `driver.data.routes[0].name`